# when (msg=='OK') its only excute else part .pls help to find solution

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jqueryform

when i send msg its show only else part which is excuted  even msg send sucessfully.its use ID #errormessage not #sendmessage.

success: function(msg) {

```
     //alert(msg);

   if(msg=='OK') {

      //msg = 'success';
      $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
      $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
      $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");

    }

   else {
      //msg = 'fail';
      $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
      $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
      $('#errormessage').html(msg);
   }

  }
```

Comment: Check if ajax result sending only OK console.log( msg ); before if( msg == 'OK' ) - check also if OK is caption. Results should be visible in browser console debug.

Comment: try if(msg.toLowerCase().trim()=='ok') . it will trim the unnecessary white space in response if any

Comment: The `//msg = 'success'` is a very suspect comment...